# AWS CloudFront: no such bucket exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am setting up the Origin Request in CloudFront,my Origin type is s3, and my Origin domain is test-1109.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com    .when i use Managed policies of UserAgentRefererHeaders, i can access Files in S3 from cloudfront. but when i use Managed policies of AllViewer, when i   access Files in S3 from cloudfront, Then it reported an error：

````
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
<BucketName>www.one.top</BucketName>
<RequestId>JEASAAS0F7T37GDT</RequestId>
<HostId>qCXoe8sa+U5ZTW5m7xw0r+AZA/ieQy8xPCQU7BWChbaxIzAuzkEDo/Th9fHaIMWFUSrJrhH8xV8=</HostId>
</Error>```
````

Answer (score 3):

when you forward all viewer headers in origin request policy which includes host header as well, than the host header will be the "www.one.top"
and then, S3 endpoint will be looking for the bucket name through the host header which in this case will be the "www.one.top".therefore a 404 bucket not found error will be returned.